# play framework 2.1.1 - package com.restfb does not exist

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.1, restfb

I'm using play framework 2.1.1, and I want to add to a project restfb in order to use Facebook graph.

I added restfb-1.9.0.JAR to eclipse, then I right clicked on it, and chose build path->add to build path.

However when I'm trying to write some code, and use the restfb package, I'm getting an error code on the browser.

This is the error:

```
error: package com.restfb does not exist
```

On the line:

```
import com.restfb.FacebookClient;
```

Any idea on how I can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting the jar in the `lib` folder of the project? See this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies _Unmanaged dependencies work like this: create a lib/ directory in the root of your project and then add jar files to that directory. They will automatically be added to the application classpath._

**Edit:** I see that restfb is on mavencentral, so it would be much better to include it to your managed dependencies like this: `libraryDependencies += "com.restfb" % "restfb" % "1.9.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Copy your libraries into the `lib` folder in your project folder. If the `lib`-folder does not exist, create it.

The Play Framework includes all jars in the lib-folder when building/compiling your app. Adding it to the eclipse-build-path is not enough.